# Prove that $10^l \equiv 10^k \pmod{10^m+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $l,k,m$ be positive integers with $l \equiv k \pmod{2m}$. Prove that $10^l \equiv 10^k \pmod{10^m+1}$.

I didn't see how to use the fact that $l \equiv k \pmod{2m}$ in order to prove this.

Comment: **Hint.** Prove that $10^{2m}\equiv 1\pmod{10^m+1} $.

Comment: We see that $(10^m+1)^2 = 10^{2m}+2 \cdot 10^m+1$, which gives that.

Comment: Then consider the difference between $10^l$ and $10^k$ and use the fact $l-k$ is divisible by $2m$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $a \equiv b \pmod{k}$ and $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, then $x^a \equiv x^b \pmod{n}$.

This holds for any positive integers $n, k$, nonnegative integers $a, b$, and and integers $x$.

This should give you the answer along with Henning's hint, if you pick the right values of $n, k, a, b, x$.